# Laravel remove duplicate record in query builder

Tags: laravel-8

Laravel remove duplicate record in query builder

I using laravel 8 and have a query like this to get all product belong to category, in result i saw some products were duplicate, im using ->distinct() to remove duplicate record and it work but number of pages divided  is wrong because count of products before distincts not changes, how can i fix it.

- This is my query:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
            ->join('category_product', 'products.id', '=', 'category_product.product_id')
            ->join('categories', 'category_product.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->where('categories.id', $id)
            ->orWhere('categories.parent_id', $id)
            ->select('products.*')->paginate(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subquery to first select distinct product IDs and then apply pagination to the result. For example:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->join('category_product', 'products.id', '=', 'category_product.product_id')
    ->join('categories', 'category_product.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->where('categories.id', $id)
    ->orWhere('categories.parent_id', $id)
    ->select('products.id')
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate(30);

// Now, fetch the full product details for the paginated results
$productDetails = DB::table('products')
    ->whereIn('id', $products->pluck('id'))
    ->select('products.*')
    ->get();
```